# How to install GIMP documentation properly on 22.04

Tags: gimp

I tried using the Ubuntu Software app to install gimp, but it didn't have the documentation and the app couldn't find the doc packages. So I used Snap to uninstall it, and then using apt I've installed gimp, gimp-help-common, and gimp-help-en. Yet when I start gimp and click on Help, it gives the error:

```
Firefox can’t find the file at /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/en/index.html
```

What's the right way to install gimp with local documentation?